# MS Unit Continuous Integration with TFS

Tags: tfs, integration, continuous

I'm tasked with creating a Continuous Integration build for our project with TFS, and one of the requirements is to create unit test continuous integration with MS Unit. How can I set up TFS to use continuous integration with MS Unit?

Thank you!

Comment: Continuous integration is just a build trigger. Just make sure your build definition runs the MS Unit tests. If you want gated check-ins, then there should be plenty of good information available on that already.

Comment: How do I make sure the build definition runs the MS Unit tests?

Comment: If you have the build definition configured to run the tests, then just check the results of the build run. It will note the number of tests passed as well as tests that failed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Team Explorer" in Visual studio. 
In the Drop down list there is a "Build options".
Once you select it you should find "New Build Definition". This is your starting point.
Here you will find various configurable points like 
In Trigger tab: Manual/Continuous etc.
In Process tab: "Disable Test", "MS Build arguments" etc.

Here is the blog post I followed to set up my build environment.
http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html
(Keep in mind that you need to enable some IIS settings to get continuous deployment to work)